# Entity Framework 4.1 - Mapping bad schema

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, database-schema, legacy-database

So I have a badly formatted schema that I can't touch right now because of a lot of legacy code dependencies.

Supposed I have a table Test and it has a column IsValid that is declared type int.

I want the poco domain object to have the proper intent of IsValid as a boolean.  When a query is applied in my repository, I want it to resolve correctly in the query.

```
.Where(o => o.IsValid == true)
```

should resolve to:

```
where isvalid = 1
```

Can the EntityTypeConfiguration map in this manner or will do I have to create a custom expression parser to look for special cases in the repository (which I prefer not to do)?  Or is there another way (without exposing multiple properties on the domain object)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a query extension method to encapsulate this code:

```
public static IQueryable<YourEntity> ThatAreValid(this IQueryable<YourEntity> source) {
    return source.Where(x => x.IsValid == 1);
}

// usage

return entities.ThatAreValid();
```